# When creating an iOS live activity I get `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ActivityKit.ActivityInput error 1.)`

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

When creating an iOS live activity I get the error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.ActivityKit.ActivityInput error 1.)
```

Answer (score 15):

One possible cause for this is not having set the `NSSupportsLiveActivities` property in your App target's `Info.plist`.

Even if you have it set in your Widget Extension make sure it's set in your App target.

It should look like this in Xcode:
[image: showing NSSupportsLiveActivities set to true]

Comment: Looks like you also need to add `NSSupportsLiveActivities` to app's `info.plist` in addition to widget's `info.plist`

And xcode 14.1 also seems to have issues if your profile has access to app containers :-(

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `Supports Live Activities` to the apps `info.plist` in addition to the widget's `info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using iPhone with 16.2 above OS versions.
When you will run a live activity on iPad it shows the same error log Because it's only supported on iPhones.