# The operation couldn’t be completed. User has denied activities for this target: What does this mean? (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14, xcode15

I'm trying to run Live Activities and Dynamic Island activities on my actual iPhone 15 Pro Max (Not the simulated iPhone). However, when I run the app, I get the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. User has denied activities for this target`. As you scroll, you'll see where I'm having the issue. What should I do?

```
 import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit
import Foundation
import ActivityKit

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var currentTime = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                
                
                ZStack { // No need to specify alignment here for individual items
                    Image("TrexlerLibraryPicture")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text(libraryClosingText())
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding([.top, .leading]) // Adds padding to the top and leading sides, moving the text towards the top left
                            .font(.title2)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)// Aligns text to the top leading edge
                            
                        
                        Spacer() // Pushes both texts to their respective edges
                        
                        Text("Welcome Emanuel!")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding([.bottom, .leading]) // Adds padding to the bottom and leading edges
                            .font(.title)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomLeading) // Aligns to bottom leading
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Home")
               
              // LOOK HERE! IT'S THIS CODE!!!
            }.onAppear() {
                do {
                        _ = try LiveActivityManager.startActivity(timeRemaining: calculateTimeRemaining())
                    print("Hello, it made it ")
                    }
                catch {
                    print(error
                        .localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        
            
            .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 60, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { _ in
                                // This block is executed every minute
                                self.currentTime = Date() // Update the current time
                            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    
                    ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "DeSalesLibraryE-Resources", title: "How to Guide"))
                    ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "BookaStudyRoom", title: "Book a Study Room"))
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "LibraryBookTech", title: "Book Technology"))
                    ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "library3dmodel", title: "Book 3D Anatomical Model"))
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "IntLoanArticleReqPicture", title: "Interlibrary Loan Article Request"))
                    ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "IntLibLoanBookReqPicture", title: "Interlibrary Loan Book Request"))
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: ContactUsView()) {
                            ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "ContactUs", title: "Contact Us"))
                        }
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: LibraryStaffView()) {
                                ServiceTiles(tile: ServiceTile(picture: "LibraryStaffPicture", title: "Library Staff"))
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}

func libraryClosingText() -> String {
    let closingTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 21, minute: 0, second: 0, of: currentTime) ?? Date()
            let now = currentTime // Use the updated current time
    
    // Format the closing time as a string
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    let closingTimeString = formatter.string(from: closingTime)
    
    // Calculate the difference in minutes
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: now, to: closingTime).minute ?? 0
    
    if (difference < 0)
    {
        return "The Library is closed"
    }
    
   else
    {
       return "The Library closes at \(closingTimeString) today (In \(difference) Minutes)"
   }
    
}


    
    func calculateTimeRemaining() -> String {
        // Implementation of your time calculation logic
        // Placeholder example:
        let closingTime = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 21, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
        let now = Date()
        let remaining = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: now, to: closingTime).minute ?? 0

        if remaining <= 0 {
            return "Closed"
        } else {
            return "\(remaining) minutes"
        }


       }
    }

#Preview {
    HomeView()
}
```

Here's the other files that might help

```
    import Foundation
import ActivityKit

class LiveActivityManager {

@discardableResult
static func startActivity(timeRemaining: String) throws -> String {
    var activity: Activity<ClosingTimeAttributes>?
    let initialState = ClosingTimeAttributes.ContentState(timeRemaining: timeRemaining)
    
    do {
        activity = try Activity.request(attributes: ClosingTimeAttributes(), contentState: initialState, pushType: nil)
        guard let id = activity?.id else { throw LiveActivityErrorType.failedToGetID }
        return id // Ensure this returns a String representation of the ID
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}

static func listAllAttributes() -> [[String:String]] {
    let sortedActivities = Activity<ClosingTimeAttributes>.activities.sorted { $0.id > $1.id }
    return sortedActivities.map { ["timeRemaining": $0.contentState.timeRemaining] }
}

static func endAllActivities() async {
    for activity in Activity<ClosingTimeAttributes>.activities {
        await activity.end(dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
    }
}

static func endActivity(_ id: String) async {
        // Assuming 'id' is a String that represents a UUID, we need to find the corresponding Activity
        // by matching its UUID string representation with 'id'
        await Activity<ClosingTimeAttributes>.activities.first { $0.id == id }?.end(dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
    }
    
    static func updateActivity(id: String, timeRemaining: String) async {
        // Here also, 'id' is a String. We match it against the uuidString representation of each Activity's UUID
        let updatedContentState = ClosingTimeAttributes.ContentState(timeRemaining: timeRemaining)
        let activity = Activity<ClosingTimeAttributes>.activities.first { $0.id == id }
        await activity?.update(using: updatedContentState)
    }

enum LiveActivityErrorType: Error {
    case failedToGetID
}
```

}

```
import Foundation
import ActivityKit

struct ClosingTimeAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        var timeRemaining: String
        
        }
    }
```

ClosingTimeBundle

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ClosingTimeBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        ClosingTime()
    }
}
```

ClosingTime.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Trexler_Library

struct ClosingTime: Widget {

var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    ActivityConfiguration(for: ClosingTimeAttributes.self ) {context in
        
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw.fill")
                        .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("~ \(context.state.timeRemaining)")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .bold()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "figure.outdoor.cycle")
                            .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Your food is on delivery")
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .bold()
                                
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("From")
                        .font(.system(size: 8))
                    Text(context.state.timeRemaining)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .bold()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Text("To")
                        .font(.system(size: 8))
                    Text(context.state.timeRemaining)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .bold()
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 20)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
            HStack {
                ProgressView(value: CGFloat((context.state.timeRemaining as NSString).floatValue), total: 100)
                    .tint(.yellow)
                    .background(.white)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
        }
        .frame(height: 160)
        .background(.black)
        
       
        
    } dynamicIsland: { context in
        DynamicIsland {
            DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw.fill")
                            .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("~ \(context.state.timeRemaining)")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "figure.outdoor.cycle")
                                .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Your food is on delivery")
                                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                                        .bold()
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                                        HStack {
                                            Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                                                .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                                .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            
                                            Text("Call")
                                                .font(.system(size: 10))
                                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("From")
                            .font(.system(size: 8))
                        Text(context.state.timeRemaining)
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                            .bold()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("To")
                            .font(.system(size: 8))
                        Text(context.state.timeRemaining)
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 20)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
        } compactLeading: {
            Image(systemName: "clock")
                .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        } compactTrailing: {
            Text(context.state.timeRemaining)
        } minimal: {
            Image(systemName: "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw.fill")
                .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
    }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491297/when-creating-an-ios-live-activity-i-get-the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed

Comment: Does the link work on Xcode 15? It's still not working for me